# Debounce a method but keep merging and memoizing the parameters

Tags: javascript, function, memoization, debouncing

I have a method defined like this

```
updateHook(obj) {
  // update the item
}
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce
const update = debounce(updateHook, 2000);
```

I want to merge all the params and call it once if the method is called multiple times within 2 seconds e.g.

```
update({ name: 'abc' }); // first call
update({ city: 'def' }); // second call
update({ cell: 123 }); // third call
.... ~2 seconds
// should send one call to update with all the params merged like
update({ name: 'abc', city: 'def', cell: 123 });
```

NOTE: Its not required to use debounce, the requirement is I just want to call a method with merged params if that method is called multiple times during a time period of 2 seconds.

Comment: this can't be readily answered without reference to the existing implementation of `debounce`.

Comment: That's not a typical use-case of debounce but it's definitely doable. You most likely need a custom implementation of `debounce` to handle it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own *higher order function* that calls the given function with merged args (see `merge` in the example below).

The biggest problem here is (IMO) that the `merge` function makes very strong assumptions about what parameters will be passed.
You'll need to judge for yourself whether you need a highly generic or very specific implementation.

```js
const {debounce} = throttleDebounce;

const merge = (fn) => {
    let merge = {};

    return (obj) => {
        merge = {...merge, ...obj};
        fn(merge);
    };
};

const updateHook = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj);
}

const update = merge(debounce(2000, updateHook));

update({ name: 'abc' });
update({ city: 'def' });
update({ cell: 123 });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/throttle-debounce@3.0.1/umd/index.js"></script>
```

---

Another problem would be the probable need to *reset* the merge function at some point. If this should correlate with the debounce timeout, then a you'll probably need a specialized *debounce factory*.

```js
const {debounce} = throttleDebounce;

const updateHook = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj);
}

const mergedDebounce = (delay, callback) => {
    let merged = {};

    const debounced = debounce(delay, () => {
        callback(merged);
        merged = {};
    });

    return (obj) => {
        merged = {...merged, ...obj};
        debounced(merged);
    };
};

const update = mergedDebounce(2000, updateHook);

update({ name: 'abc' }); // first call
update({ city: 'def' }); // second call
update({ cell: 123 }); // third call

setTimeout(() => {
    update({ foo: 42 }); // fourth call
}, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/throttle-debounce@3.0.1/umd/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: you read my mind.. indeed this is the answer(making your own merger)

Comment: I think there's a flaw with this - it doesn't empty the `merge` object once the callback is finally invoked, i.e. this is a one-shot deal.

Comment: @Alnitak I just updated the last paragraph to point that out.

Comment: well yea it does assume but.. the function *IS* for what he wanted

Answer (score 2):

```js
function updateHook(obj) {
  // update the item
  console.log('updateHook :: obj ...', obj);
}
const debounce = _.debounce;

function mergeMemoizeAndProceedWithBoundUpdateContext(data) {
  // initialize all data from the bound update context.
  const { memoizedData, proceed } = this;

  Object.assign(memoizedData, data);  // - merge into memoized data.
  proceed(memoizedData);              // - proceed with debounced function.
}
const updateData = mergeMemoizeAndProceedWithBoundUpdateContext.bind({

  memoizedData: {},                   // - provide the memoized data default.
  proceed: debounce(updateHook, 2000) // - create the debounced proceed function.

}); // create update function with bound memoization/update context.

updateData({ name: 'abc' });
updateData({ city: 'def' });
updateData({ cell: 123 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The above provided approach remains valid too for solving the currently addressed problem of clearing the memoized data by a correct timing. One just needs to provide and use an additional `clearData` method at the bound update context ...

```js
const debounce = _.debounce;

function updateHook(obj) {
  // update the item
  console.log('updateHook :: obj ...', obj);
}
const updateThreshold = 2000;

function mergeMemoizeAndProceedWithBoundUpdateContext(data) {
  const { memoizedData, clearData, proceed } = this;

  Object.assign(memoizedData, data);
  proceed(memoizedData);

  clearData.call(this);
}

function clearMemoizedData() {
  this.memoizedData = {};
}
const updateData = mergeMemoizeAndProceedWithBoundUpdateContext.bind({
  memoizedData: {},
  clearData: debounce(clearMemoizedData, updateThreshold),
  proceed: debounce(updateHook, updateThreshold),
});

setTimeout(updateData, 2500, { foo: 42 });
setTimeout(updateData, 6000, { baz: 'baz' });
setTimeout(updateData, 4000, { bar: 'bar' });

updateData({ name: 'abc' });
updateData({ city: 'def' });
updateData({ cell: 123 });

setTimeout(updateData, 9000, { biz: 'biz' });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```